# planificación de trayectoria, de java a python

Tags: java, python, class, pygame

soy nuevo en python y para aprender mas sobre el lenjuage intento realizar un programa de planificacion de trayectoria, anteriormente lo realice en java, y pense que seria sencillo transcribirlo a python, posteriormente comparar y analizar, pero debido al poco conocimiento en python, se me a complicado replicar algunos metodos de java a python.

Comenzare explicando en que consiste la planificacion de trayectoria que deseo realizar, basicamente es generar circulos de tamaño y posicion aleatoria sin que colisionen entre si para despues generar una linea que no colisione con los circulos.

coloque como comentarios en el codigo de java las partes que se me complican

codigo en python:
a continuacion la parte del codigo que se me esta complicando

```
while i < 171:
                self.choca = False
                self.r = random()*(100 +5)
                self.x = random()*(500 + self.r)
                self.y = random()*(300 + self.r)
                self.creOne = Circulo(self.ven, "white", self.x, self.y, self.r)
                for j in range (j,i):
                    self.choca = self.creOne.colisionC(self.fig[j])
                    if self.choca == True:
                        break
                if self.choca == False:
                    self.choca = self.creOne.colisionL(self.l1)
                    self.choca = self.creOne
                if self.choca == False:
                    self.fig.append(self.creOne)
                    i=+1
            return self.fig
```

a continuacion el codigo en java:

esto es lo que quiero trascribir en python:

```
while(i<100) {
                choca = false;
                r = (int) (Math.random()*100+5);
                x = (int) (Math.random()*(500-2*r));
                y = (int) (Math.random()*(300-2*r));
                cc = new Circulo(x,y,r);



                for(j=0; j<i; j++) {            
                    choca = cc.colision(fig.get(j));
                    System.out.println(fig.get(j));#una de las lineas que no logro transcribir ya que segun lo poco que se en python solo puede utilizar el get con String
                    if(choca==true) break;
                }
                System.out.println("colision " + choca + i + " con " + j);
                if(choca == false)
                    choca = cc.colision(l1);#aqui me encuentro con otro problema, resulta que el metodo colision en python existe dentro la clase circulo pero lo necesito usar en la clase linea, por lo tanto no se si esta bien en mi codigo python
                if(choca == false) {
                    fig.add(cc);
                    i++;}
                
            }
            return fig;
        }
```

y por ultimo esta parte, aqui ya empiezo a generar mis figuras pero python para hacerlo esta dentro de un bucle por lo que me realiza una infinidad de circulos

java

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.drawLine(0,0,500,300);
                    for(PosGeo fig: figs) fig.dibujar(g);
                }
```

python

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            self.UsaFig()
            self.check_events()
```

Comment: ¿por qué no coinciden ciertos números al pasar de java a python? Por ejemplo en java el bucle es `while (i<100)`, pero en python en cambio `i<171`. Tampoco coinciden las fórmulas en que calculas `r`, `x`, `y`. Debemos ignorar esos detalles o cuál es el problema si no?

Comment: @abulafia oh no los bucles eran de 171, ambos, pero en una prueba simplemente lo cambie a 100 para que tadara menos al ejecutar, y bueno, r, x, y  y son diferentes por el -2 pero al final se multiplican con numeros random asi que si ignorar esa pequeñas diferiencias

Comment: bueno lo dire por pasos, el primer problema surge dentro de while en el for, concretamente en "choca = cc.colision(fig.get(j));" cuando quiero transcribir a python no estoy seguro si estoy bien, ya que en python solo puedo usar el get con datos de tipo String, mientras que en java puedo usarlos incluso en un arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que comentar sobre tu código, pero no quisiera hacer la respuesta demasiado extensa. Menciono las más importantes:

1. No estás obligado a poner `self.` delante de todas las variables que uses. Solo es necesario si quieres que esas variables sean atributos del objeto (lo que en Java se declararía en la clase y fuera de las funciones). Esto solo es necesario si esas variables van a ser compartidas entre diferentes métodos del objeto. No me parece que sea el caso para la mayoría de las que aparecen en tu código.
2. En python puedes imprimir con `print()` cualquier tipo de datos y normalmente Python lo imprimirá de forma legible (listas, diccionarios...) la excepción son los objetos. Aunque puedes imprimirlos, lo que python imprime por defecto no es muy legible (algo como `<Object XXX at XXXX>`. Pero si en la clase de ese objeto defines un método `__str__()` que devuelva una cadena, entonces python lo usará para imprimir la cadena devuelta. Eso te permite "personalizar" como se imprime cada objeto inventado por tí, lo que puede ser útil para imprimir el círculo `cc`.
3. Python tiene muchas funciones de utilidad que ayudarán a simplificar tu código. Por ejemplo, para generar un entero entre 1 y 100 puedes usar `random.randint(1,100)` en vez de tener que andar multiplicando `rand.random()` por 100 y sumarle 1, y redondear a entero.
4. Para hacer un bucle que itere por enteros sucesivos desde A hasta B-1 usarás `for i in range(A, B)`. Y si A es cero, basta `for i in range(B)`, pero en muchas ocasiones no quieres iterar por enteros, sino por valores de una lista. Los enteros sólo los necesitas para usarlos como índices, cosa necesaria en Java, pero en Python puedes iterar directamente por los elementos sin necesitar sus índices, con `for elemento in lista`.
5. Python te permite razonar de otras formas de más "alto nivel". En lugar de tener un contador `i` para contar cuántos círculos has generado, directamente se puede hacer el  `while` sobre la longitud de la lista, ya que no necesitaremos el valor de `i` para ninguna otra cosa, gracias a que podemos usar dentro `for elemento in lista`.
6. Usa f-strings! Son una sintaxis muy cómoda para generar cadenas que contengan valores de variables. Por ejemplo; `f"La persona {nombre} tiene {edad} años"`.

Dicho todo esto, creo que una traducción más "pythónica" del código Java que mostraste sería así:

```py
import random

figs = []  # Lista donde iremos añadiendo circulos
while len(figs) < 171:
    choca = False;
    r = random.randint(5, 104)
    x = random.randint(0, 500-2*r-1)
    y = random.randint(0, 300-2*r-1)
    cc = Circulo(self.ven, "white", x,y,r)  # No sé que es 'ven' asumo que es un atributo del objeto

    for elemento in figs:
        print(elemento)
        choca = cc.colision(elemento)
        if choca:
            break
    print(f"colision {choca} entre {cc} y {elemento}")
    if not choca:
        choca = cc.colision_con_recta(self.l1)  # No sé de dónde sale l1, asi que supongo que es un atributo de objeto
    if not choca:
        figs.append(cc)
# Una vez salimos del bucle, retornamos la lista
return figs
```

Para que los `print()` de este código generen algo útil en la salida, deberías añadir a tu clase `Circulo` el método `__str__()` que podría ser así:

```
class Circulo:
    def __init__(self, ven, color, x, y, radio):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.r = radio
       ...

    def __str__(self):
      return f"<Circulo en ({self.x}, {self.y}) de radio {self.r}>"
```

De ese modo si haces cosas como:

```
c = Circulo(ven, "white", 5, 10, 30)
print(c)
```

Por pantalla saldría:

```
<Circulo en (5, 10) de radio 30>
```

Quedan detalles adicionales respecto a cómo implementas en tu clase `Circulo` la detección de colisiones. Creo entender que necesitas dos métodos, uno para detectar colisiones entre círculos y otro entre círculos y rectas, pero no me quedó claro este punto, por lo que "inventé" el nombre de ese segundo caso. Tampoco veo claro de dónde salen algunas de las variables (no sé si son parámetros de la función, atributos de objeto, o variables locales) por lo que adiviné como me pareció.

Respecto a la pregunta final, no la entiendo. Pero creo que con lo que te he contado tienes para avanzar y quizás plantear otra pregunta después más enfocada.

Comment: muchas gracias, en el punto numero uno, no me sentia comodo que todas las variables tuvieran self pero como no estoy tan familiarizado con las clases en python no estaba seguro con cual si escribirlo, en el punto numero 4 es el que mas te agradezco queria saber una forma  de interar con los valores de una lista y no por enteros, sin duda muchas gracias, no publique todas las clases porque me parece que en eso voy bien, asi que gracias y continuare con todos los datos que me has brindado, para posteriormente hacer otras preguntas, gracias

Comment: Ah, y también puedes acceder a un elemento por su índice, como en java con el get, pero la sintaxis python es simplemente `lista[indice]`